# MvcSiteMapProvider is using ascx

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

I have donwloaded the Nuget package, MvcSiteMapProvider.

In one project it only downloaded the razor views. In my other, I have both the Razor and ascx files.  Also in that project it is default to using the ascx. I want it to use the razor pages instead.  Does anyone know how to switch this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the NuGet package detects no files with a `.aspx` extension in your project or detects any files with a `.cshtml` or a `.vbhtml` extension, it will install the `.cshtml` templates. Unfortunately, there is no reasonable default when both `.aspx` and `.cshtml` extensions are detected or no files with the above extensions are detected, so this is a "best guess".

To install the Razor templates, you just need to delete the `.ascx` templates and copy the `.cshtml` templates from [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/tree/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Web/Html/DisplayTemplates).